# Initializing and re-initializing global array of strings in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have the following code

```
// global array a[100][10]
char a[100][10];

main(){
   printf("%s\n", a[0]);
   strcpy(a[0], "test")
   printf("%s\n", a[0]);
   if (some condition){
      // attempt to re-initialize a[100][10]
      char a[100][10];
      printf("%s\n", a[0]);
   }
}
```

The outputs of the printf's are (in order):
(new line)
test
n$t

My questions are: did I re-initialize a[100][10] correctly? If so, why did it output a strange result, i.e., "n$t"--I was expecting a (new line) just like before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the if you are not "reinitializing" `a`, you are shadowing the global variable and using uninitialized memory.

The first time around you only get a newline printed because the global `a` has static storage duration and is thus 0-initialized. The inner `a` has automatic storage and is not zero-initialized.

---

Depending on what you are trying to do you might need `memset` to zero `a` or something else entirely.

Comment: I tried "memset (a, '\n', sizeof(a));" in attempt to re-initialize a, but the output of "printf("%s\n", a[0]);" is like a 100 newlines, instead of just one newline. what gives?

Answer (score 1):

Check this function, it should do the trick.

[memset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/)

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling with `-Wshadow` :)

You are not "re-initializing" `a` here, just merely creating an other variable named `a`.

You first, static `a` is 0 initialized, the shadowing one is randomly initialized.